# Regarding drawBuffer in glClearBufferiv

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am rendering geometry on non default FBO and applying it as integer texture to the geometry rendered on default FBO. To clear a color on non default FBO, i am using glClearBufferiv() call. I am not getting what is drawBuffer (2nd argument) in my case. I tried with 0, but its not working. it does not clear the color.

```
GLint cl[]={32000,32000,32000,32767};
glClearBufferiv(GL_COLOR, 0, cl);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

My frag shader:

```
out ivec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
fragColor = ivec4(0,32767,0,32767);
}
```

With this, it renders green geometry but the outside color is black.

I am having 1 depth and color attachment. I am calling drawbuffers as below:

```
GLenum buffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
glDrawBuffers(1,buffers);
GLint cl[]={32000,32000,32000,32767};
glClearBufferiv(GL_COLOR, 0, cl); or
 glClearBufferiv(GL_COLOR, GL_DRAW_BUFFER0, cl)
```

But still same error.

Comment: Why does it matter what your fragment shader does? Your fragment shader does not execute when clearing a buffer.

Comment: How are either of the numbers green or black? You're writing to an *integer* buffer. It does not have a directly visible color; it's just arbitrary integers. So how do you resolve them into "green" or "black"?

Comment: I am having GL_RGB16I internal format in texture. so (0,32767,0,32767) will be green in frag shader. I don't get your point    *It does not have a directly visible color*

Comment: You cannot display an integer texture. Which means you aren't displaying it with a blit command or something; you are rendering that texture to the actual display. So there's no guarantee that the problem is in the clear and not in the part where you're rendering it.

Comment: when i use glclearcolor which is for floating textures, i get white texture. When i removed that call i can see same color which is my frag shader to a geometry on non default FBO.