# What are drawBuffers?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

The [opengl docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearBuffer.xhtml) as well as [OpenGL ES docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf#nameddest=section-4.2.1) state regarding `clearBuffer[fiuv]`:

> If buffer is GL_COLOR, a particular draw buffer GL_DRAW_BUFFERi is specified by passing i as drawbuffer

Indeed, the [WebGL spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/) defines values for `DRAW_BUFFER0` .. `DRAW_BUFFER15`

But what *are* these things? I've heard of framebuffers, and renderbuffers... but what are drawbuffers? how do I create one? What's the relationship to framebuffers? How do I know which one I'm supposed to clear if I have some deferred rendering pipeline that uses multiple framebuffers?

*note: this may seem like a duplicate of [Regarding drawBuffer in glClearBufferiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869068/regarding-drawbuffer-in-glclearbufferiv) but that question is old, tagged under OpenGL, and doesn't answer the same question exactly*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Framebuffers have attachments. Those attachments are also referred to as "drawbuffers" when a framebuffer is the currently bound `DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` as they are the buffers that will be drawn to.

There is a function `gl.drawBuffers` that let you choose which attachments will actually be written to

```
gl.drawBuffers([
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // draw to the first attachment
  gl.NONE,               // don't draw to the 2nd attachment,
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT2,  // draw to the 3rd attachment
]);
```

Note that these settings are part of the currently bound framebuffer's state. They are not global settings. (and there is a set of this state for the canvas itself when you call the function above with no framebuffer bound)

Similarly you can call `gl.clearBufferXXX` to clear a specific attachment of the currently bound framebuffer. For example clearing the 3rd attachment as in

```
const drawbuffer = 2
gl.clearBufferfv(gl.COLOR, drawBuffer, [1, 0, 0, 1]);
```

Then the 3rd color attachment on the currently bound `DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` will be cleared.  (0 being the first, 1 being the 2nd, 2 being the 3rd attachment)

The only use of the constants `DRAW_BUFFER0` ... `DRAW_BUFFER15` is to query the values set by `gl.drawBuffers`. Eg.  `gl.getParameter(gl.DRAW_BUFFER2)` gets the drawbuffer setting for the currently bound framebuffer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Banging my head against the wall...

Comment: So in your example, it will clear gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT_2 - because that is what's set to drawBuffers at index 2?

Comment: Followup question, when I clear and _then_ draw, it seems my contents are still zeroed out when I try to render the bound texture. When I remove the clear line, I can see the texture fine. Does this make sense, maybe a common mistake you've seen before?

Comment: Yes, in my example it will clear COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 of the currently bound framebuffer. note: index 2 of drawBuffers can only either be NONE or COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, any other value is invalid. As for your issue you'd need to post a new question with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Why is COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 invalid?

Comment: Because that's what [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) says. "If the GL is bound to a draw framebuffer object, the *i*th buffer listed in bufs
must be COLOR_ATTACHMENT*i* or NONE."

Comment: in regard to my other question... had to do with clearing the color buffer but _not_ the depth buffer, and so everything was black, I suppose because the previous depth was filled and so new renders failed